# How does Senator Geary know Michael Corleone's plan?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-godfather-2

In *The Godfather, Part II*, on [that scene](https://youtu.be/Re9O7kDtt6c?t=61) Senator Pat Geary says to Michael:

> GEARY: My sources tell me that you plan to make a move against the Tropicalla. They tell me within a week, you're gonna move Klingman out. That's quite an expansion.

Then Michael has a "mental conversation" with Tom that looks like:

> MICHAEL: How does he know about that? Did you leak something?
>   TOM: I have no idea.

I don't know if Tom actually leaked the information, so how Senator Geary was aware about Michael's plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### We don't know.

Senator Geary seems quite *au fait* with the Corleone's interests however insofar as he's aware of not only the family (which is, perhaps, not surprising) but also their control of various casino / gambling interests

> The Corleone family has done very well here in Nevada. You own, or, you control, two major hotels in Vegas -- one in Reno. The licenses were grandfathered in, so there is no problem with the gaming commission.
>
> Now, my sources tell me that -- you plan to make a move against the Tropicalla. They tell me within a week -- you're gonna move Klingman out. That's quite an expansion. However it will leave with one little technical problem. Ahh -- The license will still be in Klingman's name.

So, he has *sources*..presumably in local/state government.

He's also offering to influence the Licencing Board so being *in the know* and wielding the power of his office implies a certain level of information at his disposal.

---

Unfortunately, there is no base novel from which to draw more information as Mario Puzo refused to write one and no novelisation of *The Godfather II* seems to exist.

The closest we have is [*The Godfather Returns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather_Returns) by Mark Winegardner which covers some of the period involved but Geary/Klingman/the Tropicalla are not mentioned in the book.

Geary *is* mentioned in Winegardner's follow-on novel [*The Godfather's Revenge*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather%27s_Revenge) but this also has few clues.